# Applying GradCam to video classification models

Tags: cnn, rnn, visualization, computer-vision

In the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391), it says that GradCam visualization can be applied to any convolution based model. The problem is stated for convolutions that process images. In my case, I am classifying videos so therefore I should apply GradCam to every frame individually by calculating the gradients with the loss of the entire video (At least that's how I think).

The problem is that I am using different models to experiment, such as a ConvLSTM. These use convolutions in each LSTM gate, and though I return intermediate results of each frame, these are maxpooled when passed to the next layer so I cannot get activations corresponding to each frame.
But I also work with a model that uses MobileNet to feature extract each frame, and pass that to a GRU network. In this case mi approach should work?

I am nothing attaching example code because I believe this to be a theoretical question, but if need be I will.